# Change string size in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

In my Azure Data Factory project I have created a pipeline to load data from an API source to Azure SQL. However, there is one issue that I would like to fix but cannot find a solution for. I want to cast my strings to restrain their size. Right now all my strings in SQL are (MAX), which is going to slow down my performance later on.

Is there a way to specify the length of my string in ADF pipelines when I map my data.

Right now I have tried it through mapping within the Copy Data activity in pipelines. It is here that I have not found an option for string length. Do I have to make the ETL process in Data flows in order for me to be able to change the string length?

[Here you can see that I map it with string in ADF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdTpZ.png)

[This is what it is in SSMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNqlq.png)

I want to limit it so that the datatype in the server is for example nvarchar(50).

Comment: can you provide ant sample input output or provide more information on what you are exactly trying to do.

Comment: Edited the post now with examples

Comment: Are you creating the target table using auto create table option from ADF?

Comment: Pipelines are only going to see String, which translates in SQL to VARCHAR(MAX). You need to handle this on the SINK side by defining the table and schema. Best if you can do this prior to the upload, but if not, then I would call a stored procedure after the upload to reset the column sizes.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to specify the length of the string columns in copy activity. - Try to design SQL sink table with datatype as varchar (50). Otherwise, like @Joel Cochran commented, you can create stored procedure to alter the data type. Execute that stored procedure using pre-copy script in copy activity.

[image]